# Getting mysql query results based on a column value

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a MySql table with two columns namely category and name. I have 4 unique values of category and there are thousands of records in this table. But all these records fall into either of the 4 categories present in the table.

Now, What I want is that as output, I should get 2 results of each category i.e. 2 results of first category, then 2 results of next category and so on.

Is it possible with a single query ?

Comment: Can you show your table structure, some sample data and what you expect.  You have your question tagged as greatest-n-per-group which typically is not a standard query as it is an iterative process that can be done with SQL variables, but also should be limited so you are not going through an entire table of what could be millions of records... just get AT WORST CASE, entries within the last ... 30 days or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set @num := 0, @cat := '';

select category,name
      @num := if(@cat = category, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @cat := category as dummy
from MyTable
group by cateogry, name
having row_number <= 2;
```

Comment: This is where I was going, but group by uses aggregates for non-group by columns... have you tested this?  Won't it just grab the first entry for row number via the group by (unless you added row_number column).  Additionally, per my question to the poster, should have SOME limit to prevent going through the full file.

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE category = 1 LIMIT 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE category = 2 LIMIT 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE category = 3 LIMIT 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE category = 4 LIMIT 2
```